# Invalid Identifier when using concatenated join comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is my query.  v.location is a column which contains floor and room information, i.e. FL 2 RM 204.  I need to compare this against the mv_rooms table which has the room and floor split into two separate columns.

```
select v.location, v.customer_name, v.street_name
from voip_validate v, mv_rooms r, mv_buildings b
left outer join voip_validate
on v.location = 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room
where 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room is null
and b.dps_number = r.dps_number;
```

When I run the query, I get the error:

ORA-00904: "R"."ROOM": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 47

Comment: You are mixing up ANSI join syntax styles. Use one style and stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mixing oracle join syntax and ANSI.

```
select v.location, v.customer_name, v.street_name
  from voip_validate v
       left outer join mv_rooms r
                    on v.location = 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room
       left outer join mv_buildings b
               on b.dps_number = r.dps_number
 where r.room is null
```

also your where clause is totally wrong as it can never be null.

```
where 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room is null
```

were you intending to return rows that had no matching row in "V"?

Comment: I am wanting to return rows in V that are not matching up with rows in R.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy ah ok, i've amended my example for that way round. i've assumed r.room is a not nullable field. if not, put the `where r.room` as any not nullable (eg one of the PK columns) columnms

Comment: thanks.  Here is the code I am using and for the most part I believe it returns the records I'm looking for.  select v.location, v.customer_name, v.street_name
  from voip_validate v
       left outer join mv_rooms r
                    on v.location = 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room
       left outer join mv_dps_buildings b
               on b.dps_building_number = r.dps_building_number
 where r.room is null
 and r.floor is null;

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a problem with your where clause,
as you need to test the floor field and the room field for NULL, not the whole string.

```
select v.location, v.customer_name, v.street_name
from voip_validate v, mv_rooms r, mv_buildings b
left outer join voip_validate
on v.location = 'FL ' || r.floor || ' RM ' || r.room
where (r.floor is null or r.room is null)
and b.dps_number = r.dps_number;
```

There may be a problem that floor and/or room are integer data types.  Convert them to strings.

Comment: I am still getting the invalid identifier.  Could it be that my r.floor and r.room columns are of type VARCHAR2(4 byte) and VARCHAR2(8 byte) but my v.locations is VARCHAR2(60 byte)?

Comment: I just realized the other problem.  Since the where clause is finding records where floor or room is null, you cannot do the string concatenate.  Try changing is null to is not null, and then try leaving out parts of the SQL until you can get rid of the error.  That should center in on the problem.

Comment: Although your solution isn't the selected answer I believe you helped me track down some of the problems.  Thanks for your help.